# PowerShell dbatools Invoke-DbaQuery with UNC file

Tags: powershell, unc, dbatools

Within PowerShell, I want to run the Invoke-DbaQuery dbatools command and use a UNC path with the -File parameter:

`Invoke-DbaQuery -SQLInstance $SQL_host -Database $DatabaseName -File "\\file_svr\scriptdir\userlist.sql"`

The command runs without error but doesn't produce any output.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  If so, what am I missing?

Comment: I tried adding this to my script:  
   set-location -Path "\\file-srv0\SHARED\I T\22 SQL Server" 
but it produces
   set-location : Access is denied
   At line:1 char:1
   + set-location -Path "\\file-srv0\SHARED\I T\22 SQL Ser ...
   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Location], UnauthorizedAccessException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

Comment: Opened ticket 2109230040007978 with Microsoft support to try and get this figured out.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the call has been working but the output was not visible.  This is because the script has code like this:

```
DECLARE UserCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT  
  'CREATE USER ' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME([name]) + ' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME([name]) + ' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = ' + QUOTENAME([default_schema_name]) + ';'
  AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --]
FROM    sys.database_principals AS rm
WHERE [type] IN ('U', 'S', 'G') -- windows users, sql users, windows groups
AND [name] <> 'dbo'
AND [name] <> 'guest'
AND default_schema_name is not null

OPEN UserCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM UserCursor INTO @addUserScript
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @addUserScript
    FETCH NEXT FROM UserCursor INTO @addUserScript
END

CLOSE UserCursor 
DEALLOCATE UserCursor;
```

The solution then was to call the script like this:

```
Invoke-DbaQuery                  `
   -SQLInstance $HCM_SQL_host    `
   -Database $Refresh_database   `
   -Verbose 4>&1                 `
   -File "\\file-srv0\scriptdir\Userlist.sql" | `
    out-string -Width 250 | Out-File -FilePath $Create_Users_File_Fullname
```

Note the line "-Verbose 4?&1 `" that redirects the verbose output (i.e. the PRINT output) back to the standard output and, ultimately, the file.